# Python typeError

Tags: python, mechanize, typeerror

I am new to programming. I am trying to download race results using Python and Mechanize. I tried to loop through the pages by creating a `for` loop  I have included the relevant code below.
When I run this I get the following error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'instance' and 'int'

Why can't I use the variable x in the URL?

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()

for x in range(1, 3): 
    page = br.open('http://results.chicagomarathon.com/2013/?page=%d&event=MAR') % (x)
    print page.read()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to format the response of mechanize with the integer when you should be formatting the url.

The following code formats the url and then tries to retrieve it:

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()

for x in range(1, 3):
     url = 'http://results.chicagomarathon.com/2013/?page=%d&event=MAR' % (x)
     page = br.open(url)
     print page.read()
```